# ¿Cómo pasar valores de una tabla como parámetros en URL?

Tags: php, mysql, webservice

A ver si alguien me puede orientar:

Tengo un fichero .xls que debo importar a una tabla mysql. Eso lo tengo hecho. De las columnas de la tabla, una tiene un valor que debería pasarse (no sé de que manera) como parámetro a una URL para petición de datos, ejecutar la petición y guardar el resultado. Me explico:

Leo el xls y se añaden 100 registros. Cada registro, tiene un valor llamado CLAVE, que por cada registro, debe pasarse como parámetro en una URL para llamar a un webservicce y recoger el dato. Es decir, si hay 100 registros, se debe ejecutar para los 100, y de cada uno, almacenar su valor en otra columna.

Gracias,

Comment: Saludos. El WebService como tal debe proporcionarte un formato con el cual identifica cada dato que le proporcionas; así mismo lo que recibes; te proporciono este link se ve bien como para lo que necesitas https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-consumir-un-webservice-rest-con-php/ claro adaptando a tu código según corresponda. Tiene lo medular.

Comment: hola @RobertoLeOr, gracias por la respuesta. Si, la parte de pasar parámetro a un webservice a través de la URL la conocía, y lo he usado con file_get_contents. Lo que no acabo de ver es como hago para, por ejemplo, una vez que he cargaddo los datos del excel en la tabla, y los veo en pantalla, poder poner un botón tipo EJECUTAR y que lea cada valor CLAVE de la tabla, lo vaya pasando por la URL y rellene el dato a devolver para cada registro. No se si en un bucle, estoy algo perdido.